# Rails: How to force ActiveRecord generate alias for an association every time (just like Hibernate in Java does it), not only when it's ambiguous?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel, sti

I work on a project where there is STI `Item` with 5 subclasses (`Item1`, `Item2` ... `Item5`). This STI (`items` table) is mapped over a join table `item_parents` to `Parent` record (`parents` table) record. The mapping is done via `has_many trough:`.

Each of the items has two fields: `name`, `code` both are strings. `Parent` has many fields, but for the sake of example let's say it has `name`, `created_at`.
On the frontend, they are displayed in one table, like this:

`Parent.name | Parent.created_at | Item1.name | Item1.code | Item2.name | Item2.code | ...`

Users can configure filtering for each of the columns. It can be any combination or no filter at all. For example, they can choose the following combination:

```
Parent.created_at before 2020.02.22
Item1.name containing 'abc'
Item2.name containing 'xyz'
Item3.code equals 'Z12'
```

The filtering code implemented like this:

```rb
def search(filters)
  filters.reduce(Parent.all) { |query, (key, value)| apply_filter(query, key, value) }
end

def apply_filter(query, key, value)
  case filter_key
  when :parent_name_contains
    query.where(Parent.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{value}%"))
  when :parent_created_at_before
    query.where(Parent.arel_table[:created_at].lt(value))
  when :item1_name_contains
    query.joins(:item1s).where(Item1.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{value}%"))
  when :item2_name_contains
    query.joins(:item2s).where(Item2.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{value}%"))
  when :item1_code_equals
    query.joins(:item1s).where(Item1.arel_table[:name].eq(value))
  when :item2_code_equals
    query.joins(:item2s).where(Item2.arel_table[:name].eq(value))
  # ... and so on for all the filters
  else
    query
  end
end
```

### The problem

When I query by fields of two or more different subclasses of `Item`, ActiveRecord fails to generate correct `WHERE` clause. It does not use the alias that it has assigned for the association in `JOIN` clause.

Let's say I want to filter by `Item1.name = 'i1'` and `Item2.name = 'i2'`, then what rails generates is this:

```sql
SELECT "parents".*
FROM "parents"
         INNER JOIN "item_parents"
                    ON "item_parents"."parent_id" = "parents"."id"
         INNER JOIN "items"
                    ON "items"."id" = "item_parents"."item_id"
                        AND "items"."item_type" = 'Item::Item1'

         INNER JOIN "item_parents" "item_parents_parents_join"
                    ON "item_parents_parents_join"."parent_id" = "parents"."id"
         INNER JOIN "items" "item2s_parents" -- OK. join has an alias
                    ON "item2s_parents"."id" = "item_parents_parents_join"."item_id"
                        AND "item2s_parents"."item_type" = 'Item::Item2'

WHERE "items"."name" = 'i1' 
  AND "items"."name" = 'i2' -- Wrong! Must be "item2s_parents"."name" = 'i2'
```

As a result, I have zero rows returned, because it's impossible to have an item with name equal to `'i1'` AND `'i2'` at the same time.

### What I tried

It seemed to be a good idea to write a custom `joins_item` method, that would dig the `query` and check whether it has other `joins` called on it before (AR stores such information in `query.values[:joins]` and `query.values[:left_outer_joins]`) and if there is, then it would return another `Arel::Table` instance having the correct alias. If there is nothing joined before, then I don't need alias and return the default `Arel::Table`.

But then I found out that AR resolves aliases at the moment of building SQL. So even though I could guess the correct alias (or no alias) at the moment of joining it can change in the end. And this is actually what happens when you do `left_outer_joins` first and then `joins`. AR always places `INNER JOIN`s before `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s in the resulting SQL.

### So the question is...

Is there a way to force AR to alias everything when I do `joins` or `left_outer_joins` with Arel, or any other more or less maintainable workaround/fix/monkey patch for this issue?